# SmbFileInputStream Throwing Fatal Exception: main

Tags: java, android, samba

I am trying to read an xml file from a file system using samba. My app crashes with the only error being:

`FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                        Process: com.example.imac.chs_pharmacy, PID: 2615
                  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`

It crashes on the line:

```
SmbFileInputStream fXmlFile = new SmbFileInputStream(sFile);
```

I have also used this line instead, with the same result:

```
InputStream fXmlFile = sFile.getInputStream();
```

Here is the code snippet I am using:

```
try {
    String user = "user";
    String pass ="pass";

    String url = "smb://ip/public/chs/" + message + ".xml";
    Log.d(TAG, url);

    NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null, user, pass);

    SmbFile sFile = new SmbFile(url, auth);

    SmbFileInputStream fXmlFile = new SmbFileInputStream(sFile);

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    }
```

I am not sure why it's not working, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html) is used as a wrapper to indicate that an exception arises in the static initializer block or the evaluation of a static variable’s value.

Thus, we have to ensure that the original exception is fixed, in order for the JVM to be able to load class successfully.